# Can’t connect to internet, wifi is ok, can ping ok from command window, but Chrome and Firefox can’t connect

Tags: wireless, browser

Firefox and Chrome not connecting to WiFi, but can ping to Google successfully.  This was after an update from 18.04 to Focal Fossa.

My cat walked on the keyboard during update from 18.04, and had to do a reinstall.

Comment: Your details are *unclear* to me, you mention a *release-upgrade* from 18.04 to 20.04, then mention a problem with the cat & need to re-install, but aren't clear as to what you actually re-installed. What are you running?

Comment: Sorry. I was upgrading to 20.04, and somewhere during the install I got the white screen saying something went wrong (presumably with the install).  [The suspect is my cat who walked on the keyboard.].  Rebooted in terminal and am able to start Ubuntu 20.04 now, but can’t get anywhere with the internet connections (although I have a good wifi connection and can ping google).